# Populate a new Google Sheets sheet, with a random sample, with at least X samples of a given attribute

Tags: google-sheets

I have a data set which I would like to take a random sample from and place in to a new sheet. I have one extra constraint / stratification: I would like X examples of each of a given attribute.

For example, if COL A has 5 rows of Apples, 5 rows of Bananas etc., I would like a random sample which includes 2 Apple rows, 2 Banana rows and so on for as many values of COL A as there are.

I am halfway there having got [a formula to populate a new sheet with a random sample](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/W4eCbzvLi7U;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/select$20random$20rows):

```
A1: =ArrayFormula(FILTER( SORT('My list of 100000 rows'!A:A ;RANDBETWEEN( 0+ROW('My list of 100000 rows'!A:A) ; ROWS('My list of 100000 rows'!A:A)); TRUE); ROW('My list of 100000 rows'!A:A)<=100))
```

but this doesn't give me the ability to select a minimum or exact number of instances of each unique attribute.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Write a script to do it for you - you'll have all the customization and constraints you want to enforce, with easy and comprehensible use of `if` tests and `for` or `while` loops. See the Google Apps Script documentation (and web documentation for Javascript 1.6)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like a random sample which includes 2 Apple rows, 2 Banana rows and so on for as many values of COL A as there are.

Insert two columns to the left of your data and in A1:

```
=choose(randbetween(1,10),"12","13","14","15","23","24","25","34","35","45")
```

in B1 and copied down to suit:

```
=countif(C$1:C1,C1)
```

then :

```
=query(A:D,"select C,D where B contains '"&left(A1)&"' or B contains '"&right(A1)&"' ")
```